# Primary Key Constraint Error when using Merge oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Requirement : I have one huge table (say haivng lacs records) with duplicate entries for when we combine three columns value together.  My requirement is to populate second different table having unique records (removing duplicates from first table).

For this requirement as we have to do bulk inserts in second table, I came across MERGE feature of oracle 10g, which is more optimize way for bulk insert.  But when I tried this I am getting integrity constraint error for composite primary key(three cols that I mentioned above).

```
MERGE INTO 2ndTable e
USING firstTable h
ON (e.firstCol = h.firstCol and e.2ndCol = h.2ndCol and e.3rdCol = h.3rdCol)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (h.firstCol, h.2ndCol, h.3rdCol);

composite primary key for 2nd Table : e.firstCol, e.2ndCol, e.3rdCol
```

Please let me know your thought for this error OR the best way we can handle this bulk inserts removing duplicate records.

Comment: Who said `MERGE` is better optimized than bulk insert? How are the two related? Moreover, when you have primary key defined over three columns, how can they contain duplicate data?

Comment: integrity constraint, means it refers another table?

Comment: Please Check, if any NULL exists as well.!

Comment: What is the problem with `insert x as select distinct a1,a2,a3 from y` ? why is merge necessary here ?

Comment: Sorry I said I am getting integrity constraints error ... It was primary key constraint error.

Comment: Also... for the 1st table I am not having primary key for the three cols... and that's the reason I am having duplicate records considering those cols.